# copy from one table column values to second table in conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update DF1 with values from DF2['city'] , both tables have different size, and all are in pandas df.

```
DF1:

name  years  job
miki  21     worker
adam  22     PM
mike  51     director
wiola 33     manager

DF2:

name  years  city
miki  21     NY
adam  22     CAN

Result:

DF1:
name  years  job       city
miki  21     worker    NY
adam  22     PM        CAN
mike  51     director
wiola 33     manager
```

I need to take into account only `name` and `years` columns, if they are same as in second table , just take `city` value.

I have tried to do:
`DF1[DF1['name']==DF2['name'],'city']=DF2['city']`

but its only for one condition `city`, i can do separatelly sam for `years`
But main problem is that i cant do that for different tables ,
i am receiving error: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

could anyone help me?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['name', 'years'])`

Comment: hi, i am receiving error : `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

Comment: Then try `cols = ['name',' years']; pd.concat([df1.set_index(cols), df2.set_index(cols)], axis=1), join='outer')`

Comment: now i am receiving : `pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` , also i deleted one `)` after `axis=1`

Comment: Then heed the warning and fix the error: `df1['years'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['years'], errors='coerce'); df2['years'] = pd.to_numeric(df2['years'], errors='coerce'); df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['name', 'years'])`